# SciPy image resizing shift - expected behavior or bug?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy

I noticed something odd with the scipy.misc.resize -- it seems using any interpolation method other than 'nearest' results in a roughly 1x1 pixel shift away from (0,0) in the resulting image.

Here's a totally synthetic example of taking a 3x3 image to 6x6 :

```
>>> src
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,  64.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.]])

>>> imresize(src, (6, 6), interp='bicubic',mode='F')
array([[  1.,   0.,  -5.,  -8.,  -5.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ -5.,   0.,  25.,  40.,  25.,   0.],
       [ -8.,   0.,  40.,  64.,  40.,   0.],
       [ -5.,   0.,  25.,  40.,  25.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]], dtype=float32)
>>> imresize(src, (6, 6), interp='bilinear',mode='F')
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,  16.,  32.,  16.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,  32.,  64.,  32.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,  16.,  32.,  16.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]], dtype=float32)
>>> imresize(src, (6, 6), interp='nearest',mode='F')
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,  64.,  64.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,  64.,  64.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Now it seems that the center of mass moves for bilinear and bicubic interpolations, but does not move for the nearest interpolation. This occurs for both odd and even destination sizes.

I realize that varying definitions of coordinates being pixel-center or pixel-edge or treating pixels as point samples or rectangles will give slightly different results during resampling, but this seems like a major problem (unless I'm missing something).

Here's another example that demonstrates the shift more clearly:

```
>>> imresize(src, (7, 3), interp='bilinear',mode='F')
array([[  0.       ,   0.       ,   0.       ],
       [  0.       ,   0.       ,   0.       ],
       [  0.       ,  11.4285717,  11.4285717],
       [  0.       ,  25.1428566,  25.1428566],
       [  0.       ,  25.1428566,  25.1428566],
       [  0.       ,  11.4285717,  11.4285717],
       [  0.       ,   0.       ,   0.       ]], dtype=float32)
```

Since no horizontal size change occurred, I would not expect the horizontal coordinate of my center of mass to move at all, but it clearly moves from from 1.0 to 1.5.

So, is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: This is very interesting. I have observed similar things even in `PIL`, but have no immediate explanation. Your reasoning about "pixel-center" and "pixel-edge" may be a lead (although this suggests that pixels are squares instead of 0d points), as well as border considerations and additional effects with non-integer multiple resizing. Very interested in anything that may shed light here.

Comment: Turns out that scipy actually uses `PIL` (see the `toimage` function elsewhere in [this file](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/misc/pilutil.py#L392))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is definitely a bug. I wrote the following short snippet:

```
from scipy.misc import *
from scipy.ndimage import measurements
import numpy as np

src = imread("src.png")
cbc = src
lnr = src
nrs = src

for idx in xrange(0, 128):
    cbc = imresize(cbc, tuple(2 * i for i in cbc.shape), interp='bicubic', mode='F')
    cbc = imresize(cbc, src.shape, interp='bicubic', mode='F')

    lnr = imresize(lnr, tuple(2 * i for i in lnr.shape), interp='bilinear', mode='F')
    lnr = imresize(lnr, src.shape, interp='bicubic', mode='F')

    nrs = imresize(nrs, tuple(2 * i for i in nrs.shape), interp='nearest', mode='F')
    nrs = imresize(nrs, src.shape, interp='nearest', mode='F')

    imsave("nrs_%03d.png" % (idx), nrs)
    imsave("lnr_%03d.png" % (idx), lnr)
    imsave("cbc_%03d.png" % (idx), cbc)
```

and the bilinear/bicubic images literally walk away from (0,0) every image, while nearest stays aligned.

I'll check with PIL/SciPy folks to see if it is already fixed or not.

Comment: Did you end up filing a bug report with PIL and/or SciPy for this? I am having trouble with this behavior now.